# Error when I try to write in mongo setCollectionSharded:already sharded

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Environment:

- MongoDB 3.0
- Java 6
- mongo-java-driver-2.12.3.jar

When I try to write in mongo 3.0 I get this error

```
13:45:50,095 ERROR [com.mongo.MongoTraceManager] error.mongo.trace.setCollectionSharded:already sharded
13:45:50,096 ERROR [com..mongo.MongoTraceManager$1] error.mongo.trace.run: java.lang.Exception: Error trying to mark mongo collection 'log_2016_02' as hashed: already sharded
at com.mongo.MongoTraceManager$1.run(MongoTraceManager.java:76) [:]
```

What could it be?

Comment: Erm... The collection might already be sharded? Have you had a look at `sh.status()` on the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the driver mongo-java-driver-2.12-3.jar is not compatible with Mongo 3.0, so to get a support with the version 3 of mongo we need the driver mongo-java-driver-2.13 or higher.

**mongo-java-driver-2.13.jar** and higher (support MongoDB 3.0)